# Python - Calling Multiple Functions (Unresolved Reference). When to use a global variable?

Tags: python, function

I've just started learning functions and I understand the basics, however I don't understand how to call them in more complex scripts (such as below).

The example script below is attempting to pull football results from a MySQL db, extract to CSV, then import from CSV and place into a HTML table and send as an email. The issue I am having is that I need to compile the output of each function (e.g. Premier League, League One, League Two) into a report table - which I achieve using 'report':

```
report = ""
report += htmlpremleague
report += "<br><br>"
report += htmlleagueone
report += "<br><br>"
return report
```

Which is joining the table so I can send all the results in one email as a HTML table. The issue I am having is that 'report' can't locate the HTML's e.g. 'htmlpremleague' due to it being in a function. But I can't simply replace it with `"report += premier_league()"`as there is other stuff in that function, not just the html. Ideally i'd like to get functions working because (a) it's fun learning them! and (b) it would be cool to be able to run each individual league on their own, e.g. generate a report solely on premier league. The example script below runs fine, however this is due to the report html part being global and sitting outside of the functions. Ideally i'd like them inside so I can achieve the above.

I'm new here and i've tried to stick to the guidelines but please let me know if i've done anything incorrect, or I can provide anything further.

To reiterate, the desired output would be for everything to be in a callable function e.g. Alternatively, would I just place 'report' / each table as a global variable?

```
def league_one():

    query = "SELECT footballteam as ftt, goals, points FROM 
    footballdbl_league_one plfdb ORDER BY point desc"
    leagueonecursor.execute(query)
    leagueonerows = leagueonecursor.fetchall()


    with open('league_one.csv', 'wb') as file2:
        wr = csv.writer(file2, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerow(["Team", "Goals", "Points"])
        wr.writerows(leagueonerows)
        print ("csv2 created")

        textleagueone = """
        """
        htmlleagueone = """
        <html><body><p><u><h3><b>Highest Run Time</b></h3></u></p>
        {table2}
        <br><br>
        </body></html>
        """

        with open('league_one.csv') as input_file2:
            reader = csv.reader(input_file2)
            leagueonereader = list(reader)

            textleagueone = 
            textleagueone.format(table2=tabulate(leagueonereader, 
            headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))
            htmlleagueone = 
            htmlleagueone.format(table2=tabulate(leagueonereader, 
            headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))
```

/Main Example Football Script:

```
con = pymysql.connect(user='',password='',host='',database='')
cursor = con.cursor()

# probably not necessary
premleaguecursor = con.cursor()
leagueonecursor = con.cursor()

def premier_league():
    query = "SELECT footballteam as ftt, goals, points FROM footballdbl_prem_league plfdb ORDER BY point desc"
    premleaguecursor.execute(query)
    premleaguerows = premleaguecursor.fetchall()

    with open('prem_league.csv', 'wb') as file1:
        wr = csv.writer(file1, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerow(["Team", "Goals", "Points"])
        wr.writerows(premleaguerows)
        print ("premier league csv created")

textpremleague = """
"""

htmlpremleague = """
<html><body><p><font size="+1"><u><h3><b>Premier League</b></h3></u></font></p>
{table1}
</body></html>
    """

with open('prem_league.csv') as input_file1:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file1)
    premleaguereader = list(reader)

textpremleague = textpremleague.format(table1=tabulate(premleaguereader, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))
htmlpremleague = htmlpremleague.format(table1=tabulate(premleaguereader, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))

def league_one():

    query = "SELECT footballteam as ftt, goals, points FROM footballdbl_league_one plfdb ORDER BY point desc"
    leagueonecursor.execute(query)
    leagueonerows = leagueonecursor.fetchall()


    with open('league_one.csv', 'wb') as file2:
        wr = csv.writer(file2, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerow(["Team", "Goals", "Points"])
        wr.writerows(leagueonerows)
        print ("csv2 created")

textleagueone = """
"""

htmlleagueone = """
<html><body><p><u><h3><b>Highest Run Time</b></h3></u></p>
{table2}
<br><br>
</body></html>
"""

with open('league_one.csv') as input_file2:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file2)
    leagueonereader = list(reader)

textleagueone = textleagueone.format(table2=tabulate(leagueonereader, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))
htmlleagueone = htmlleagueone.format(table2=tabulate(leagueonereader, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))

# def league_two():

# def league_three():

def report():
    report = ""
    report += htmlpremleague
    report += "<br><br>"
    report += htmlleagueone
    report += "<br><br>"
    return report


def send_email():

    report()
    me = ''
    password = ''
    server = ''
    you = ''

    message = MIMEMultipart(
        "alternative", None, [MIMEText(report, 'html')])

    message['Subject'] = "FOOTBALL REPORT"
    message['From'] = me
    message['To'] = you
    server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(me, password)
    server.sendmail(me, you, message.as_string())
    server.quit()

def main():
    premier_league()
    league_one()
    report()
    send_email()
```

Comment: Questions with lots of detail - bit long though - maybe construct a smaller exaple instead of pasting all your code - see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Simply provide the data you need in your `def` to it - I choose to do it as list, you could also pass it serarately like this `def report2(myOne, myTwo): ...` and call it as `report2(one,two)` - no need to use globals for that.

```
def leageOne():
    # do stuff
    stuff = "MyLeageOneResult"
    return stuff

def leageTwo():
    # do otherstuff
    otherstuff = "MyOtherResult"
    return otherstuff

def report(myInputList):
    return '<br/>'.join(myInputList)


one = leageOne()
two = leageTwo()

email = report([one , two])

print email
```

Output:

```
MyLeageOneResult<br/>MyOtherResult
```